# How to convert Array to CanvasPixelArray OR create a CanvasPixelArray object?

Tags: javascript, canvas, pixel

I got pixel data of an image in PHP that I would like to transfer to Javascript.

My only problem is that PHP returns a string that I convert in Javascript Array and the ImageData.data is not an Array, but a CanvasPixelArray.

```
var cvsPixelAr = [arStrFromPHP];
var imgData = ctx.createImageData(dim[0], dim[1]);
imgData.data = cvsPixelAr;
```

I also tried "new CanvasPixelArray();", but still nothing.

Someone knows a work around?
If not I will use web workers to change every single value :-/.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you will have to copy the items over piecewise into the final data array:

```
var imgData = ctx.createImageData(dim[0], dim[1]);
var d = imgData.data;
for (var i=0,len=d.length;i<len;++i) d[i] = cvsPixelAr[i];
```

Comment: Thanks for keeping my syntax.
That's what I did, but I wanted to avoid the loop.

Comment: AFAIK, You can't avoid the loop. Im guessing here but it's probably due to what returns as ImageData.data varies depending on the JS engine used but most importantly, ImageData.data is an internal type and therefore you cannot access it's constructor via plain ol' JS. It sucks teh fun out of reduceRight()'ing pixels!

Comment: since you're generating some of your JS via your PHP you can probably generate some [unrolled loops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unwinding) to optimise

Answer (score 0):

For me, this worked quite well:

```
ctx.putImageData(
    new ImageData(someUintArray, width, height ),
    0,0
);
```

Don't forget that this formula must apply:

```
someUintArray.length == width*height*4
```

You definitelly do not need to copy whole array. Check [MDN docs on this topic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData/ImageData).

Here's an example where I use this to resize image without DOM API, just using the raw pixel data: https://jsfiddle.net/n3drn8v9/4/